# UITableView will change contentOffset in iOS8 with swift3, is this a Swift3 bug?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

When I migrated my swift code from 2.3 to 3.0 in Xcode8, I found UITableView with some different height of cells will change contentOffset  by itself after reloadData in iOS8. But everything was fine in swift2.3.

I printed contentOffset in cellForRowAt: and scrollViewDidScroll: function like below:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("In scroll: \(scrollView.contentOffset)")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("In cellForRow offset: \(tableView.contentOffset)")

    //...
}
```

Same code run with different version of swift, have different result.

[image: changed in swift3]

In swift3, after reloadData, it will change contentOffset by itself in iOS8.

[image: no change in swift2.3]

In swift2.3, without this problem.

My entire test project uploaded my GitHub repository, you can check or git clone from https://github.com/heqichang/swift3-tableview-issue, and run my code in your phone with iOS8.

Is this swift3's bug?

[image: shake in iOS8]

**UPDATE**

I just test my code in iPhone5s with iOS8.4 and iPhone6p with iOS10.0.2.

Comment: you have just write in "cell" of cellForRowAt indexPath => cell.selectionStyle = .none

Comment: You can turn Off bounce feature may be it helps.

Comment: @iParesh Sorry, my mistake. I didn't clarified my problem. I mean tableview will change content offset after call reloadData.

Comment: @Anuraj I tried turn Off bounce, still have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable cell selection style in **cellForRowAt** indexPath: IndexPath by this code:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

or in storyboard at inspector:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't clarified my problem. I mean tableview will change content offset after call reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing: `UITableView` may now change its `contentOffset` during the `UITableView.reloadData()` and `layout()` processes.  Hence, code such as:

```
someTableView.reloadData()
someTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos), animated: false)
```

does not guarantee that the table will be offset at `xPos`, `yPos` after the reload.  (I consider this a bug, Apple.)

One workaround that's working for me is to force the table to layout before setting the `contentOffset`:

```
someTableView.reloadData()
someTableView.layoutIfNeeded()
someTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos), animated: false)
```

Like the questioner, I too am seeing this in a table with variable height cells, so that may be a factor.

Comment: I found swift3 in iOS8 will miss last row in heightForRowAt: after call reloadData. I switched section and row to solve my problem.

Comment: @QichangHe - What do you mean,"I switched section and row to solve my problem?"  Sounds interesting!

Comment: return 1 in numberOfRowsInSection, return cell's number in numberOfSections.